# Python - getting lost around async

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

As the title said - I'm having a problem with async stuff. What I'm trying to achieve is written under every function. Sadly in this state of code I'm getting and error:

`TypeError: object StreamReader can't be used in 'await' expression` and at the end `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`

I was googling for a while and didn't really find a solution for my thing. Is there anyone who can help me a bit and clear what am I doing wrong? Am I allowed to have 2x `async with ..` in one async function?

Thanks!

```
 
def load_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        content = [a.strip() for a in content]
    return content

### --> Getting list of urls

async def task(session, item, urls):
    async with session.get(item) as resp:
        image_bytes = BytesIO(await resp.content)

### --> Downloading the image and getting image bytes

    async with session.post(
        TORCH_URL, data=image_bytes, headers={"authorization": TOKEN}
    ) as resp:
        response = await resp.json()
        print(response)

### --> Sending the image bytes to an API and getting a little json file as a response 

async def asyncmain(urls, path, content):

    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [task(session, url, urls) for url in content]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

### --> Gathering the tasks with .gather()

@click.command()
@click.option("--urls", "-u", is_flag=True, help="Use this if you have urls")
@click.option(
    "--path",
    "-p",
    help="Path to file with variant IDs, can be combined with -u (having urls in file)",
)
def main(urls, path):
    tasks = []
    content = load_file(path)
    asyncio.run(asyncmain(urls, path, content), debug=True)

### --> Fire asyncio.run with some params

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will lead to more folks willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the improper use of the `resp.content` variable below.

```py
async def task(session, item, urls):
    async with session.get(item) as resp:
        image_bytes = BytesIO(await resp.content)
```

See aiohttp's [streaming response content](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#response-content-and-status-code) documentation.

> While methods `read()`, `json()` and `text()` are very convenient you should use them carefully. All these methods load the whole response in memory. For example if you want to download several gigabyte sized files, these methods will load all the data in memory. Instead you can use the `content` attribute. It is an instance of the `aiohttp.StreamReader` class. The gzip and deflate transfer-encodings are automatically decoded for you:
>
> ```py
> async with session.get('https://api.github.com/events') as resp:
>     await resp.content.read(10)
> ```

You can either

- (a) download chunks and store them into disk, or
- (b) if the binary is not large and can be stored into memory  -- which seems to be the case based on your use of `BytesIO` -- use `io.BytesIO(await resp.read())` (see [binary response content](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html?highlight=resp.read#binary-response-content).)

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for explanation! I kinda expect to have a problem right there and I was probably too tired to realise it. Then I noticed I have more issues in the code anyway haha :))